# Ahlfors elementary mappings of regions

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

In the section "A survey of elementary mappings", Ahlfors talks about various types of regions that can be mapped to the unit disc.  What I'm confused about are the methods and regions he's talking about.

1. He writes

> The main tools at our disposal are linear transformations and transformations by a power, by the exponential function, and by the logarithm

by this does he mean that we can use linear transformations and transformations by a power, which we implement using the exponential and the logarithm?  Its a bit confusingly worded.

2. He then talks about regions whose boundary consists of two circular arcs with common end points.  Is this simply describing a crescent shaped region?  I've been visualising this as the intersection of two great circles on the Riemann sphere, like an orange slice
3. He then generalises to a circular triangle with two right angles.  he then says if the third angle has a vertex $a$, and if the sides from $a$ meet again at $b$.  Surely this is only has two sides, and is therefore not a triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I don't think so. I think he means linear transformations, integral powers and $\exp$ and $\log$.

He may mean arbitrary powers
$$
z \to z^a = \exp(a \log(z))
$$
for any $a$.

I haven't looked at Ahlfors for a long time. You can probably tell from the surrounding text, where there should be examples.

2. A crescent or a lens (which is a fat orange slice).
3. Imagine a lens (with angle $a$). Cut that lens into two pieces by a circle that crosses both lens arcs at a right angle.

[image]

In this picture all eight triangles have circular sides and two right angles.  (Remember the exterior triangle.)

Comment: so for point 3, where does the vertex $b$ where the two sides meet again go?  If they meet again at a point isn't that just the same as 2?

Comment: See my edit, with a picture.